# assignment to incompatible pointer type double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, singly-linked-list

I am trying to add nodes right after the *add pointer in my linked list
my struct and code is as follows, but shows an error in (*add)->next = new_node:

```
    typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
    }node;

    void create_node(node **add,int dat)
    {
        if((*add) == NULL)
        {
            (*add) = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            (*add)->data = dat;
            (*add)->next = NULL;
        }

        else
        {
            node *new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            new_node->data = dat;
            new_node->next = (*add)->next;
            (*add)->next = new_node; //assignment to incompatible pointer type error
        }


    }
```

Comment: So what? What is you problem exactly?

Comment: (*add)->next = new_node shows incompatible pointer type error

Comment: There is NO need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation.

Comment: @Gautam You fixed your code and now the error you're asking about is gone.

Comment: Like magic isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring `next` as a pointer to `struct node`, but there's no `struct node` in your code (only the typedef `node`).

You need to give a name for the struct in order to refer to it in the declaration of `next`:

```
typedef struct node {
```

Currently `struct node` refers to a different, unrelated struct (that you haven't defined).